# Internet explorer 11 - Security Warning when running protractor tests

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, protractor

I am using Windows 7 64 bit HP laptop.

Initially when trying to run protractor Selenium scripts, it was typing the user name and password very slow.

When researching, I found out that I need to have 32 bit IE driver. I manually downloaded 32 bit IE driver to C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium

Now my scripts are running. But the browser minimizes and Maximizes (Flickers). I have set the zoom level to 100% and privacy all zones unchecked.But each time I get this security warning.

I have enabled settings for display mixed content in IE options and restarted my computer.

I still get this security warning message when running tests.

My Config

```
 multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  }, {
   'browserName': 'firefox'
 },{
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
         acceptSslCerts: true,
         trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
  }],

 // // // // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory.
  specs: [
    '../tests/*.spec.js'
  ],
```

Please advise

Comment: What security warning are you talking about? Could you please provide a text of this warning?

Comment: Hi Michael - Here is the warning. The current webpage is trying to open a site in your Trusted sites list. Do you want to allow this? Current site:  about:blank, Trusted site: Mytesturl